# Pass along data from Input Selection into ValueBox in Shiny

Tags: input, shiny

I am trying to pass along values from a Shiny input parameter into a ValueBox.  I have seen versions of this, however I cannot seem to get it to work.  Below is a sample of what I am trying to do.  I would like to have the selections from the input field pass along to the ValueBox, and the value box returns another column (sum is fine, or just the value of the column).  Its hard with mpg data because there is not a one to one relationship of manufacturer and the city column but in my dataset one entry in the drop down aligns with one entry in another table.  I cannot seem to pass along the the input list to the valuebox.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic boxes"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput('column', 'Column:', mpg$manufacturer)
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    valueBoxOutput("vbox")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$vbox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      paste('Sum', input$column),
      sum(mpg$cty[[input$column]])
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic boxes"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput('column', 'Column:', unique(mpg$manufacturer))
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    valueBoxOutput("vbox")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$vbox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      paste('Sum', input$column),
      sum(mpg$cty[mpg$manufacturer %in% input$column])
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]